# Cannot calculate distance with latitude and longtitude

Tags: java

I have a SQLite table with latitude and longitude written in it. When I try to calculate a distance with it, I get wrong answer.

```java
public​​ArrayList​<​Double​> getPoints (){

​ArrayList​<​Double​> location = ​new​​ArrayList​<>();

​SQLiteDatabase​db = t​his.​getReadableDatabase();

​Cursor​cursor = db.rawQuery("​select latitude,longitude from "​+​Table_Name_Location,​​null)​; i​f(​cursor.getCount() > ​0)​{

​while​(cursor.moveToNext()) {

​Double​latitude = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("​Lat")​); ​Double​longitude = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("​Longi")​); location.add(latitude);

location.add(longitude);

} }

cursor.close();

​r​eturn​location;​ }

private​​double​distance(​double​lat1, ​double​lon1, ​double​lat2, ​double​lon2) { ​double​theta = lon1 - lon2;

​double​dist = ​Math.​sin(deg2rad(lat1))

* ​Math.​sin(deg2rad(lat2))

+ ​Math.​cos(deg2rad(lat1))

* ​Math.​cos(deg2rad(lat2))

* ​Math.​cos(deg2rad(theta));

dist = ​Math.​acos(dist); dist = rad2deg(dist);

dist = dist * ​60​* ​1.1515;​ r​eturn​(dist);​

}

​private​​double​deg2rad(​double​deg) { r​eturn​(deg * ​Math.​PI / ​180.0)​;

}

​private​​double​rad2deg(​double​rad) { ​r​eturn​(rad * ​180.0​/ ​Math.​PI);

}
```

Expected output is 4800 kilometers (distance between Saint-Petersburg and Moscow).
But the actual result is 9000 kilometers.

I use Android 9.0 and Java 11

Comment: There are problems with the formula. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance and possibly here: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula#Java

Answer (score 0):

As Jean-Claude pointed out, take a look at harvesine.

```
public double distance(double p1LatRad, double p1LongRad, double p2LatRad, double p2LongRad) {
    double sinLatDiff = Math.sin((p1LatRad - p2LatRad) / 2.0);
    double sinLongDiff = Math.sin((p1LongRad - p2LongRad) / 2.0);
    double a = sinLatDiff * sinLatDiff + Math.cos(p1LatRad) * Math.cos(p2LatRad) * sinLongDiff * sinLongDiff;
    return 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a)) * 6_378_100;
}
```

Also, do not implement your own radians conversion. You can use built in Math.toRadians and Math.toDegrees functions.